# Sending emails by SES as fast as possible without exceeding the rate limit

Tags: node.js, email, aws-sdk, amazon-ses, rate-limiting

I'm currently using SendGrid to send emails from many serverless node.js Lambda functions, and planning to transfer from SendGrid to SES (because of the reasonable price).

SendGrid's rate limit is so high that sending emails to users using for-loops by some lambda functions concurrently never caused a problem. But SES has lower rate limit (50 emails per second in my case), and maximum sending rate limit exceeded error occurs.

How is it possible to send emails as fast as possible without exceeding the rate limit?

My current plan is to send email request to SQS queue by many lambda functions, and receive SQS message to send emails by 1 Lambda function running without stopping time. But I'm not sure how to control the speed of sending requests to SES.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## My conclusion

I decided to create two SQS queues (A and B). Queue B is for triggering an email sending function, and queue A is for adding messages in the waiting queue. So I only need to control the speed of moving messages from queue A to B, and that makes everything simple.

[image]

I considered the following things.

## Error handling

At first, I was thinking of using while-loops to send many emails by a single Lambda function, but that makes error handling difficult. When the rate limit exceeded error or some other unexpected exception occurs, it's necessary to wait for a while and retry, but it could exceed the timeout of Lambda function.

## Scalability

Receiving 50 messages from SQS queue and sending 50 requests to SES in 1 second by a single Lambda function could be possible, but if the rate limit goes up to 300 or 500, it might be impossible to handle that many requests in a second. Moving messages from one SQS queue to another, in order to invoke a Lambda function per email, is relatively easy to scale.

## Email priority

Signup confirmation email with a verification code needs to be sent instantly, but campaign emails can be sent on a delay. With two SQS queues, I can control the priority.

## AWS cost

Invoking a Lambda function for each email takes more time than sending many emails in a single Lambda function, but the AWS cost for that is not very expensive. If it takes 1 second to send a request to SES, it costs 0.000002083 USD for Lambda execution with 128 MB memory (N.Virginia region). That's only 0.02083 USD for 1000 emails and can be ignored.

Comment: I'm on the exact same situation as you. I would like to know how you handle your function to send emails with SES max rate limit. Since you are using SQS triggers, if you dont have signup confirmation emails the queue will feed only with N messages per second from your waiting queue, but, if you have a burst on signup confirmation emails the number of messages going to SES can exceed the rate limit. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @ArmandoRodríguezAcosta That is not handlded properly, but it's working good, at least for me. In my case, 99% of all emails are daily system notifications and only 1% is a very important message that should be sent instantly. I allocate 10% of rate limit for this 1% so that 10x spike can be handlded. It could spike more, but that can be handlded by exponential backoff. https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/how-to-handle-a-throttling-maximum-sending-rate-exceeded-error/

Comment: @rhythm After some time, if queue A stops receiving messages, how would you stop your scheduled lambda ?

Comment: @ronakpatel In my case, I don't stop the lambda function. If queue A has no messages, lambda function will complete in a second. So, even it runs every minute, it will cost only $0.1 per month (128MB memory).

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [Lambda Reserved Concurrency feature](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html) to limit the number of concurrent Lambda executions to 50. And set the batch size for SQS to 1 message.

In serverless framework, this will look like:

```yaml
  sendNotificationsEmails:
    handler: lib/send-email/handler.handler
    reservedConcurrency: 50
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn: xxxxx
          batchSize: 1
```

This will ensure you won't have >50 Lambda instances running at the same time.

But then a new problem arises - if your function executes too fast in <1s, you'll end up exceeding the rate limit. You have 2 options now:

- Retry requests until they succeed
- Reduce `reservedConcurrency` proportionally

If you decide to reduce `reservedConcurrency`, let's say your code runs in 500ms. This means, if you have 50 concurrent Lambda instances, they will send 50 emails in the first 0.5s, then attempt to send 50 more emails in the 2nd 0.5s.

Then set `reservedConcurrency` to `25`. But I still recommend having retry code around `aws-sd`

Answer (score 0):

The following approach guarantees that you'll have **x** concurrent calls while your `arrayWithAllTheEmails` contains **x** or more elements.

Every time one call ends it calls the next one.

```js
let ongoing = 0

function sendXEmailsAtATime (arrayWithAllTheEmails, max = 50) {
  while (ongoing < max) {
    ongoing++
    const params = prepareParams(arrayWithAllTheEmails.shift())

    ses.sendEmail(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
      else     console.log(data);           // successful response

      ongoing--
      if (arrayWithAllTheEmails.length > 0) {
        sendXEmailsAtATime(arrayWithAllTheEmails, max)
      }
    });
  }
}

function prepareParams (oneItemFromTheArrayWithAllEmails) {
  // ... here you prepare the params and return it
}
```

Comment: SES is rate-limited by requests per second, not concurrent requests. If one request takes 200 milliseconds, your function will send 50 requests concurrently in the first 200 milliseconds of a second, and try to send more requests in the 800 milliseconds left, which will cause the rate limit exceeded error.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

I think you create a scheduled event using CloudWatch and trigger your event every 1 second or 2 seconds and it will call the lambda function. Inside lambda function only retrieve process 50 messages from SQS and ends the lambda function.

**Solution 2**

But I have seen you have put this `running without stopping time`.

If you want to do so then you will have to put a time counter from the start of sending the email requests to SES to the moment 50 requests are sent.

If the time difference is greater than 1 second then process the next set of emails.

If the time difference is less than 1 second then wait for the remaining time and then process the next set of emails.

The SES documentation is discussing the same issue at this link and its suggesting the introduction of rate limit logic in your code.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/how-to-handle-a-throttling-maximum-sending-rate-exceeded-error/

As you are using node so you can have a look at this rate limiter library https://www.npmjs.com/package/ratelimiter

Comment: As of this writing CloudWatch events have a minimum time precision of one minute. You cannot configure one to fire at sub minute intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a sleep().

```
 async function init() {
      console.log(1);
      await sleep(10000);
    }
```

Comment: There is no sleep function within node so I assume you mean the sleep package? This should not be used in production as it locks the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

**For everyone coming here in 2023:**

Amazon introduced the maximum concurrency of AWS Lambda functions when using Amazon SQS as an event source feature, which seems to be a good use case for this task. [source](https://github.com/michaelhaar/Heimdall-Burstable-SES)

Here's how we implemented the throttling:
https://github.com/michaelhaar/Heimdall-Burstable-SES

Comment: I just implemented a SQS - lambda -ses setup by the use of maximum concurrency. I however resorted to the lambdas always taking exactly 1000ms to complete, or longer if that were ever to happen for some reason. It would be interesting to see how you solved it but your github link is not working. Cheers

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Should be public now